# Tags inside spoilers show

Tags: bug, design, markdown, spoilers

When I was browsing through a stackexchange site recently, I noticed this:

[image: Tags showing through a spoiler section]

As you can see, the tags [chemistry](/questions/tagged/chemistry) and [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) were showing through the spoiler section. The cause for this is that the spoiler css masks the color property of the tag, but not the background-color, so the blue background bleeds through.
Here is an image of the css:
[image: css showing that color is overwritten but background-color is not]
(It's quite small so you'll have to open it in a new tab and zoom in).
As you can see from the strikethrough, the color is being overwritten by the spoiler but the tag is not.

> This is an example of a spoiler. When this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is fixed, the tags [random](/questions/tagged/random) and [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) should not show through.

Please fix this by changing the css for spoilers to overwrite background color!